# how to populate uitableviewcell data to other class?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

my code snippet //

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
// [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

if(indexPath.section == 0)
{
    if(indexPath.row == 1)
    {
        WebServiceHandler *handler = [[WebServiceHandler alloc]init];

        handler.requestType = eSuburb;

        NSMutableURLRequest *searchDetailsRequest = [Service parseGetSuburb:nil];

        NSLog(@"user details request of str== %@",searchDetailsRequest);

        [handler placeWebserviceRequestWithString:searchDetailsRequest Target:self Selector:@selector(getListOfSuburb:)];


    }
```

after response it jumps into another class with list of all it is data,among all those data I want to populate with it one which user selects

Comment: Can you provide more data

Comment: @bhavyakothari all i have is this only,

Comment: - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    
    if (cell == nil)
    {cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [getDatafromSearch objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    
return cell;
    
}

Comment: i got all my data into cell,now all i want to do is to pass selected data by user  to calling cell of another class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how you are doing this, but here is how if you are using segues. In this example, each of my table cells contained their relative information in an NSMutableDictionary. The receiving view controller had a NSMutableDictionary property to receive all of the sent data. The last two lines create a ViewController object and has its Dictionary property equal the Dictionary being sent from the selected cell in the table view.

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    NSString *identifier = segue.identifier;

    if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"SegueName"]) {
        // first get data
        NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow;
        NSMutableDictionary *cellData   = self.aDictionary[selectedIndexPath.row];

        ViewController *nextViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        nextViewController.aDictionary = cellData;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for ur comment,when a user tap on a Cell that should be only passed to the calling cell of another class

Comment: In your tableview, when a user selects a certain cell, you want the app to move to the next view and use the data from the cell tapped, right?

Comment: Not to the next view,actually to the previous view which calls it,thanks in advance

Comment: Upon returning to your table view, update the cell you want and then reload your table view with the data you want. - (void)reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation

Comment: - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    
}
i am returning from here,so how come i can update my cell in previous tableviewcell

Comment: Check out this link: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewAndDataModel/TableViewAndDataModel.html . You probably want to look at creating a delegate protocol, but I'm still not 100% sure how you have everything setup. Look at Listing 3-2 in particular. Sorry I couldn't be more of a help.

Comment: thanks a lot man .I have done this one using callback methods.thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would Suggest against using the callback method here. That is not the right way to carry this out.

According to my understanding, what you want to do is once the user selects a row, you wish to pass the selected row's data back to the viewcontroller(lets assume 'vcA') which called the one with the tableview('vcB')...

If this is so you should create a protocol and hence use a delegate to notify the viewcontroller 'vcA' about the selection event and hence pass the required data just as @inertiatic suggested.

Comment: yeah your approach is right,so is mine.but i am not using storyboard and as i am a newbie to iOS i don't know much about creating delegate.Thank you @aish.
I would love if u give me some assistance for making delegate method

Comment: sure i would be happy to help you regarding this. Protocols and delegates do take some understanding... [tutorial](http://quique123.wordpress.com/2012/06/07/passing-data-example/) check out this, let me know if you still need help. i'd be happy to help... :)